# How To Set Format Of Multiline Comment in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

By default IntelliJ is formatting multiline comment as

```
/*
A multi line comment
Line 2
*/
```

I would like it to format the multiline comment as

```
   /*
    * A multi line comment
    * Line 2
    *
    */
```

to match the code style standard used by other developers who use Eclipse on my team.

I've combed through the Settings Java Code but cannot find a way to force IntelliJ to automatically put an * at the beginning of each line in the multiline comment.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that comments in the copyright section are commented by default the way you would like it.

But you can do the same with your comments by using live templates. Just follow this steps...

**Define your Live Template**

- File > Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S on Windows)
- Editor > Live Templates
- Add a new one or edit an existing one, like 'sbc' (block comment)
- Edit the Teplate Text like in the following picture

[image]

**Use the Live Template**

Now if you type sbc in your code

[image]

You can expand it to

[image]

And with Enter, you can add more commenting lines

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We can achieve the same with <kbd>/**</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to alter the format of the multiline comment such that it automatically adds **/ at the end of the block instead of just */?

Comment: I am not sure about that. BTW, can you please eloborate on why would you want to have the closing comment block as **/ as */ itself is sufficient to mark end of the comment block.

Comment: it's more a personal thing and has nothing to do with whether */ is sufficient.  I grant that it is but my OCD gets triggered when the opening and closing of the comment is asymetrical.

Comment: @Christoph U can add a live template similar to `@ hce` answer and add `**/` to comment closing 

trigger: /**
template:
/**
 * $comment$
 **/

Comment: But that is for javadoc. You might not want to write the comment as a javadoc but simply a multiline comment (not with double *)